# JSON и ссылка

Tags: json, ссылки

Помогите пожалуйста.
В JSON есть 2 параметра:
1) название
2) ссылка
Как сделать что бы название(1) при клике переходило по ссылке(2)

Comment: где это должно хоть быть?

Comment: В таблице
echo "<tr><td>".$object['title']."</td><td>".$object['link']."</td></tr>";

Comment: Телепаты догадываются что дело происходит в php, ну так сделайте $object = json_decode($json)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант вот так:

```
"<tr><td><a href='".$object['link']."'>".$object['title']."</a></td><td>".$object['link']."</td></tr>";
```

Ну, а если вам нужно именно из 2-рой получить то

```
"<tr><td onclick='window.location.href=document.getElementById(\"link\").innerHTML'>".$object['title']."</td><td id='link'>".$object['link']."</td></tr>";
```